# Can "in noncontact with" be used as an antonym of "in contact with"?

Tags: prepositional-phrases

> The magnet force keeps the objects in contact with each other.

I am trying to rewrite the sentence above I created such that it has an opposite meaning. My examples are as follows:

> 1. The magnet force keeps the objects in non-contact with each other.
> 2. The magnet force keeps the objects apart from each other.

I would like to know which is better. I found a lot of sentences using the expression "in non-contact with" on google, but it seems that most of them are written by non-natives.

Comment: An antonym of "in contact with" in the metaphorical sense of being in frequent conversation with a person would be "out of touch with."

Answer (score 2):

I would use the second example:

> The magnetic force keeps the objects apart from each other.

I've never heard anyone say "non-contact" in this context before.

Another way to say this:

> The magnetic polarization keeps the objects separated from each other.

Comment: "magnetic force" not "magnet force" tend to be used

Answer (score 1):

"In non-contact with" doesn't work here. So go with "keeps the objects *apart* or *separated* from each other."

We use "non-contact" as an adjective to describe various things in which 
contact isn't made:

> Rugby is a contact sport; basketball is a non-contact sport.
>
> Friction is a contact force, but the magnetic force is non-contact.

(Note magnetic force, not "magnet force")